# Send() EPIPE only issue for Safari

Tags: c, linux, macos, sockets, networking

So, for a large video file, I am receiving (reading) from a server, and transmitting back to client (acting as reverse proxy) in C. I do this in a loop (chunk at a time).

Specifically with Safari, I get an EPIPE on the send back to the client and the full video file is not sent and can’t be played in browser (but doing the trace, a good amount of bytes were sent). Setting MSG_NOSIGNAL fixes this and all the bytes get sent (chunk at a time).

Why is this the case? Setting MSG_NOSIGNAL causes SIGPIPE not to be sent to me, but why does it allow me to send data correctly and continue to do so? From my understanding, Safari has closed its socket for this to happen (it’s the only browser this is an issue on).

Comment: Baring any code you show I can only speculate that you are not implementing the protocol properly and thus implicitly rely on implementation details in the protocol stack of the browsers - i.e. works for some browsers but not others. If you expect help in this issue please follow [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).